# PHP login form connected with SQL Server doesn't work

Tags: php, html, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am currently trying to create a login form for a project I am working on, but I can't find what I did wrong.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- <title>Animated Login Form</title> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>User Login</header>
    <form action="user-login.php">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="email" required>
        <label>E-mail</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input class="pswrd" type="password" id="password" required>
        <span class="show">SHOW</span>
        <label>Password</label>
      </div>
      
      <div class="button">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="msg()">
      </div>
    </form>


</body>
```

Also, here's the PHP script (user_login.php) where I tried to establish the connection with the SQL Server, catch the user/password submitted through the html form and check if they're in the database.

```
<?php

#starts a new session
session_start();

#includes a database connection
$serverName = "."; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Proiect_Colectiv", 
"UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

#catches user/password submitted by html form
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

#checks if the html form is filled
if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
echo "Fill all the fields!";
}else{

#searches for email and password in the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE Email(SQL Table 
column)='{$email}' AND Parola(SQL table column)='{$password}'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

#checks if the search was made
if($result === false){
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
   echo "Email/password not found";
}else{

#creates sessions
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
   $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
   $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
}
#redirects user
header("Location: homepage.html");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Your PHP application's users are not the same as SQL Server's users. In this context the people trying to login are users of your PHP application while your PHP application itself is a user of SQL Server. Your PHP application needs to supply its own values of `uid` and `pwd`, which are credentials of an SQL Login that already exists in SQL Server -> Security -> Logins, then your application code manages the credentials of your human users in the `dbo.Users` table. p.s.: don't store plaintext passwords in databases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix some issues in your code:

- As a general rule - always use parameterized statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), *...`sqlsrv_query()` function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.
- If you want to get the number of rows in a result set, you need to use `sqlsrv_num_rows()`. The function `sqlsrv_has_rows()` checks if the result set has one or more rows, so using `(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1)` is simply wrong. Note, that `sqlsrv_num_rows()` requires a client-side, static, or keyset cursor and will return `false` if you use a forward cursor or a dynamic cursor.

As an additional note, do not store passwords as plain text in a database (make a research about how to store a password in a database).

The following code, based on the code in the question, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
<?
// Starts a new session
session_start();

// Includes a database connection
$serverName = "server\instance";
$connectionInfo = array (
    "Database" => "Proiect_Colectiv", 
    "UID" => "SqlLoginName", 
    "PWD" => "SqlLoginPassword"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Connection could not be established.";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
echo "Connection established.";

// Catches user/password submitted by html form
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if (empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    echo "Fill all the fields!";
    exit;
}

// Searches for email and password in the database
$query = "
    SELECT [id], [name], [user], [level] 
    FROM [dbo].[Users] 
    WHERE Email = ? AND Parola = ?
";
$params = array($email, $password);
$options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);  
if ($result === false){
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// 
if (sqlsrv_num_rows($result) != 1) {
    echo "Email/password not found";
    exit;
}

// Creates sessions
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
    $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
}

// Redirects user
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);  
sqlsrv_close($conn);
header("Location: homepage.html");
?>
```